# ReSharper To-Do Explorer regex pattern for pragmas

Tags: regex, resharper

In our code-base, there is the convention of placing warning pragmas to indicate certain pieces of code (e.g. todo items, remarks, etc.):

```
#warning PMO 2012/04/19 Some remark here
    var t = 1;
    // and other pieces of code...
```

Is there a way to let ReSharper's To-Do Explorer find these pragmas? I've added an item with this as search expression:

```
(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>PMO)(\W|$)(.*)
```

This would search only items for me (my initials being 'PMO'). I've also tried:

```
(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>warning)(\W|$)(.*)
```

and

```
(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>#warning)(\W|$)(.*)
```

I've tried several combinations of the 'In comments', 'In strings' and 'In identifiers' options, but nothing is ever found.

Is my regex wrong (though I based it on existing regexes, and putting 'PMO' in the normal code somewhere isn't a problem)? Or maybe ReSharper ignores pragmas? I'm guessing it 's the latter. If so, does anyone have a decent alternative (besides 'Find in solution')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't currently parse preprocessor directives for its To-Do manager, so chances are what you're trying to achieve is impossible right now.
There's a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-71440) to implement this, so you might want to vote and watch.